# Take sign ups on one site and programmatically create user accounts on a sub domain

Tags: plugin-members

I have a client on a bootstrap budget looking to take payments on one site and then dynamically create a user account based on the information provided on a subdomain.

Is anyone aware of any plugins that may facilitate this or a good approach to take?

My initial thinking is to use Gravity Forms on the subdomain to take the payment and create the account and to have the form display within an `<iframe>` on the primary domain.

Does anyone see any holes in my method?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it these way:

1. Create api on subdomain ( user registration, may be some checks for is email registred atc. )
2. When on primary domain user has payed and filled out form - send these data to api ( on subdomain ), check, register, or alter an error.
3. On primary domain you can echo eny data from api on subdomain ( just needs an api call to return data ).

Back to your question: eny solution has a holes, aldought i'm not an expert, but with iframe you give more space to work with ( for some bad guys ), but with api u have calls, wich u can check and throw an errors is fomething not right.

Whait for someone, more familiar, with security issues to answer )